# Facebook logout by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I am developing a simple web game with my friends. I have integrated facebook login using the javascript sdk provided by FB. Basically, the first page of the web game is main.html, in which I added successfully a Facebook button using the code provided by Facebook:

```
<script>

// This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
  function statusChangeCallback(response) {

console.log('statusChangeCallback');
console.log(response);
// The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
// app know the current login status of the person.
// Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
// for FB.getLoginStatus().
if (response.status === 'connected') {
  // Logged into your app and Facebook.
  window.location.href = "mode.html";
} else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
  // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
    'into this app.';
} else {
  // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
  // they are logged into this app or not.
  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
    'into Facebook.';
}
}

// This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
// Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
// code below.
function checkLoginState() {
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  statusChangeCallback(response);
});
}

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
appId      : 'xxx',
cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                    // the session
xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
version    : 'v2.3' // use version 2.3
});

// Now that we've initialized the JavaScript SDK, we call 
// FB.getLoginStatus().  This function gets the state of the
// person visiting this page and can return one of three states to
// the callback you provide.  They can be:
//
// 1. Logged into your app ('connected')
// 2. Logged into Facebook, but not your app ('not_authorized')
// 3. Not logged into Facebook and can't tell if they are logged into
//    your app or not.
//
// These three cases are handled in the callback function.

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  statusChangeCallback(response);
});

};

// Load the SDK asynchronously
(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

// Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
// successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
function testAPI() {
  console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
    'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
});
}
 </script>
<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
 </fb:login-button>
```

Once login is successful, the page would be directed to another html page. In that html page, I tried to add an Facebook logout button. Trying for some hours, in vain. The most frequent error obtained is something like "FB is underfined".
Finally I decided to download a .png of FB logout button and include this .png as src image to "make" a button by myself, still in vain, rather frustrating.

The code I included in that another html page is as follows.

```
<script>

// This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().  

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
  appId      : 'xxx',
  cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                    // the session
  xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
  version    : 'v2.3' // use version 2.3
 });


// Load the SDK asynchronously
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


 function fbLogout() {
      FB.logout(function (response) {
          //Do what ever you want here when logged out like reloading the page 
          window.location.reload();
      });
  } 

</script> 

<button id="fblogout" onclick="fbLogout();""><img src="src/logout_fb.png">                    </button>
```

The error I retrieved from the Chrome console is "Uncaught ReferenceError: fbLogout is not defined"

Comment: Why is `fbLogout` in HTML comments?

Comment: you mean the onclick="fbLogout();" ?

Comment: i googled and found this kind way to call a js function from html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the "Enable logout button" at the plugin page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/login-button

That will give you a button like this:

```
<div 
  class="fb-login-button"
  data-max-rows="1" 
  data-size="medium" 
  data-show-faces="false" 
  data-auto-logout-link="true" />
```

If you use that code, you will either see a Login or Logout button, depending on the state. This can be used with the normal FB SDK for Javascript.